# Upload images by setting specific size with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to upload multiple files with codeigniter with requirement below:

1. User can upload whatever width and height of image
2. Max size of image is 10 MB
3. After uploaded, I want to get two images. dimension of **first image** is width=700, height=auto. create thumbnail for **second image**. its size is  width=100, height=auto.
4. I want to remove original file

Could anyone help me?

Thank in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function do_upload()    
{    
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';       
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';    
$config['max_size']    = '1024*10';    
$this->load->library('upload', $config);        
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())       
{    
$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());    
$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);    
}       
else       
{        
$data=$this->upload->data();    
$this->thumb($data,700,false);        
$this->thumb($data,100,true);       
unlink($data['full_path']);       
$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);      
}      
}             
function thumb($data,$thumb_size,$create_thumb)    
{       
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';    
$config['source_image'] =$data['full_path'];      
$config['create_thumb'] = $create_thumb;    
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;    
$config['width'] = $thumb;     
$config['height'] = $thumb;     
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);    
$this->image_lib->resize();    
}
```

for reference [here]:http://www.tutsmore.com/tutorials/codeigniter-image-upload-with-mysql/